# Using C# ResourceWriter to target different .NET versions

Tags: c#, .net

I have a tool that creates .NET resource assemblies programmatically, the tool is written in C# and is compiled using .NET v4.0.  On occasion this tool needs to generate resource assemblies that target .NET v3.5.  The online doc suggests that this can be done using the TypeNameConverter property of the ResourceWriter object I am using to write the resources with but I have had no luck finding an example of how this is actually done.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: That's not possible.  You cannot convert, say, a v4.0.0.0 System.Drawing.Bitmap to the v2.0.0.0 version.  You'll always end up with the v4 version, the CLR always remaps the System.Drawing.dll reference.   That ends poorly if the consumer is an app that targets 3.5.   You'll need to build two versions of this tool.

Comment: Thanks Hans.  Do you think I am misinterpreting the documentation of ResourceWriter.TypeNameConverter - "Gets or sets a delegate that enables resource assemblies to be written that target versions of the .NET Framework prior to the .NET Framework 4 by using qualified assembly names."  I have been misled by MS doco before so it is not out of the question...

Comment: Probably not, but it is just a small piece of the puzzle.  The object needs to be serialized as a .NET 2.0.0.0 object as well.  That requires fooling BinaryFormatter.  Visual Studio needs to do this when you create a project that target an older version, how it does it is a well-kept secret.  Probably has something to do with in-process side-by-side CLR support that an unmanaged app like VS can take advantage of.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone else wanting to do something similar I've found a way to do this.  I've changed my tool so that it's built against ('targets') .NET v3.5 and I control which CLR the tool gets loaded into using entries in it's app.config file as shown below.  By switching the order of the entries in the config file I am now able to generate CLR 2.0 resource assemblies from .NET v3.5 source assemblies and CLR 4.0 resource assemblies from .NET v4.0 source assemblies.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<startup>
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
  <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
</startup></configuration>
```

Good link here about app.config entries: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152935%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

In hindsight I probably should have mentioned in the earlier description of the problem that I didn't need to ***change*** the CLR target between the source assembly and it's resource assembly, just needed consistency between the two.